# C11 Nested Initialisation

Tags: c, c11

In C11, is there a way to create a nested initialisation to achieve what I have outlined in the 'test_successor_set'?

Google searches for nested C11 initialisation so far haven't shown any examples.

Perhaps it isn't possible.

I've got this far, but I can't get it to work.

```
typedef struct my_node_successor_struct {
   char *node_name;
   float cost;
} my_node_successor;

typedef struct my_node_successor_set_struct {
   const char *successor_name;
   my_node_successor *successors[];
} my_node_successor_set;

my_node_successor_set test_successor_set[] = {
 { .node_name = "S", .successors = { { .successor_name = "A", .cost = 2.f}, { .successor_name = "C", .cost = 3.f }, }},
 { .node_name = "A", .successors = { { .successor_name = "B", .cost = 1.f}, { .successor_name = "C", .cost = 1.f }, }},
 { .node_name = "C", .successors = { { .successor_name = "G", .cost = 3.f}, }},
 { .node_name = NULL, NULL },
```

};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

You've got a structure with a flexible array member at the end of it (the only place it can appear).  But you can't initialize the arrays of such structures, and you can't create an array of such structures legitimately (because all elements of an array have to be the same size, and the point of a FAM is to have variable sizes, and in any case, the array is not counted in the size so you could only have zero elements in the FAM array).

The relevant section of the standard, ISO/IEC 9899:2011 is

> #### §6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers
>
> ¶3 A structure or union shall not contain a member with incomplete or function type (hence,
>   a structure shall not contain an instance of itself, but may contain a pointer to an instance
>   of itself), except that the last member of a structure with more than one named member
>   may have incomplete array type; such a structure (and any union containing, possibly
>   recursively, a member that is such a structure) shall not be a member of a structure or an
>   element of an array.
>
> ¶18 As a special case, the last element of a structure with more than one named member may
>   have an incomplete array type; this is called a flexible array member. In most situations,
>   the flexible array member is ignored. In particular, the size of the structure is as if the
>   flexible array member were omitted except that it may have more trailing padding than
>   the omission would imply. However, when a `.` (or `->`) operator has a left operand that is
>   (a pointer to) a structure with a flexible array member and the right operand names that
>   member, it behaves as if that member were replaced with the longest array (with the same
>   element type) that would not make the structure larger than the object being accessed; the
>   offset of the array shall remain that of the flexible array member, even if this would differ
>   from that of the replacement array. If this array would have no elements, it behaves as if
>   it had one element but the behavior is undefined if any attempt is made to access that
>   element or to generate a pointer one past it.